# Creating a new menu and an item right under it for uploading excel template in google sheet(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets, menu, import-from-excel

I created an item named “import” under the menu “database” in my google sheet. What I want to execute with this item is that the excel file, with two columns only, can be uploaded and the values nested within them can be stored in an array without appending a new spreadsheet for this excel file. However, I got stuck in “how to upload excel file” this way. After loading the array with the newly uploaded data, another function will be called to add the name-style pair which doesn’t exist in sheet 1 from the array to the unoccupied cells. So this item is designed for updating the sheet1 automatically.

```
function interface() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var menu=ui.createMenu("Data base")
  menu.addItem("Import","cal")
  menu.addToUi()
}
function onOpen(){
  interface()
}  

function cal() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("updated list");// I don't know how to accomplish this part so I created a sheet to store the data as an alternative for the time being.
var lastRow=ss.getLastRow()
var dataBase=ss.getRange(2,1,lastRow,1).getValues()// I want to store the valuse nested within this two columns but there is an error when I use "indexOf" to pick out the data which doesn't exist in sheet1 and push it to the unoccupied cells so I only take one column of values here(Making it one level deep only).
var dataBase2=ss.getRange(2,2,lastRow,1)
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1")
var lastRow1=ss1.getLastRow();
var storedData=ss1.getRange(2,1,lastRow1,1).getValues()// Faced with the same problem as described above.
for(var i=0; i<lastRow1;i++){
  
  if(storedData.indexOf(dataBase[i])==-1){
    var counter=1
    ss1.getRange(lastRow1+counter,1),setValue=dataBase[i]
    ss1.getRange(lastRow1+counter,1),offset(0,1),setValue=dataBase2[i]// The error "offset is not defined" shows up here
    Logger.log(ss1.getRange(lastRow1+counter,1),setValue=dataBase[i])
    counter++
  }
}
}
```

[Sheet1 is the worksheet used for looking up who takes charge of which style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjLqh.png)

[Updated list contains the data which I want to add to the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRtqn.png)

The logic is that me and my team mates can just take a look at the sheet1 to look for the merchandiser(Name) to know the style he or she takes charge of. But this list should be updated at least once a week. So I wonder if it's possible to automatically add the names and styles in the "updated list" to sheet1 when there is no match found.
For example:
Jason   S55567899 and
Nick    Jack52578 should be added into worksheet1 right below the last occupied row since these two styles don't exist in sheet1 yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand `What I want to execute with this item is that the excel file, with two columns only, can be uploaded and the values nested within them can be stored in an array without appending a new spreadsheet for this excel file.`. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about it, can you provide the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Sorry it's my fault. I didn't make it clear. I want to create an item(like a button) in google sheet. Right after clicking on it, there should be a box jumping out for uploading the excel file. Once it's done, the values nested in the excel file(There are only two columns) will be stored in the array. I don't want to create a new worksheet for storing these data for the sake of simplicity from the user vantage.

Comment: Please take a look at he newly uploaded picture. That's the window which should shows up after clicking on "Import" under the menu "Data base".

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that you want to upload a XLSX file and you want to use the values from the uploaded XLSX file. If my understanding is correct, I have one more question for understanding your goal. I apologize for this. In your question, what are the 2 images? I cannot understand about the relationship between your sample images and the uploaded XLSX file. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your current issue and your goal. But I would like to try to understand it. So can you give me a time to do? When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: @Tanaike
Thanks for taking your time to view my question. I am still trying to come up with a better way to present my question such that it's easier to understand.

Comment: @Tanaike  I think the crux of the problem is how to create a button(in the menu of google sheet) and assign the script of importing excel file to it. Right now if I want to paste the data from excel to google sheet I have to create a new sheet to store the data. I want to avoid this step by creating the button for only taking the values nested within the first two columns of the excel file and storing it in the array.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood about `I think the crux of the problem is how to create a button(in the menu of google sheet) and assign the script of importing excel file to it.`. And I think that this can be achieved using Google Apps Script and Javascript.

Comment: But, about `Right now if I want to paste the data from excel to google sheet I have to create a new sheet to store the data. I want to avoid this step by creating the button for only taking the values nested within the first two columns of the excel file and storing it in the array.`, I cannot understand about the relationship between this and your 2 sample images. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?